# boolean function: check whether first expression is executed or the second

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have a boolean return from a function which suggests 2 checks and according to the result a message is displayed

example:

```js
<script>
function guessTheNumber(p1) {
  const test = 5;
  return p1 > 6 || p1 === test ;
}
</script>
```

displayed text

*{{ greater (if first expression is executed) || {{ equal (if second expression is executed) }}*

Comment: A boolean return value simply won't convey enough information for that. You'll need to refactor into two functions, or make the return value more nuanced than a boolean.

Comment: @JeffBowman I have a disabled button related to the displayed message, I can't refactor the computed property because **:disabled** attribute could accept only one method

Comment: That still sounds like two methods or computed properties. One is enum-like and tells you which expression passed for the sake of the message, and then a second method that accepts the result of the first and returns a boolean about whether to disable the field. I imagine you could even put the logic from the second directly into the field, like `:disabled="guessTheNumber === 'equal'"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These conditions can be expressed in the markup...

```
{{ p1 > 6 ? 'greater than 6' : (p1 === 5 ? 'equal to 5' : 'neither' ) }}
```

Or, the way I prefer, in a method that's understood to produce a string for the markup...

```
<!-- in the markup -->
{{ theThingAboutP(p1) }}

// in methods: {}
theThingAboutP(p1) {
  if (p1>6) return 'greater than 6';
  if (p1===5) return 'equal to 5';
  return 'neither';
}
```